# Can I change the name of the guake tab to show the current command?

Tags: command-line, guake

I use guake very heavily, and ssh into more than 3 computers at any point in time. I also have daemons running on some tabs (terminals). What I want to know, Is it possible to have the name of the current command as the name of the Terminal? Rightclikcing a tab, and changing its name causes this: (Look at the tab after Terminal 5)

[image: Look at the tab after Terminal 5]

Thanks.

Comment: See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/295628/30266) to a related question to show an abbreviated representation of the current directory as tab title.

Comment: What do you mean with "current command"? is there always a command running in each terminal? what should the title be when there is nothing running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a guake (0.4.1) bug.
I just see and solve this problem via this bug report though the author say this is not the best method:　https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/205

> i've found out that moving the dialog
>   destruction code (guake.py line 983)
>   down after the code that sets the tab
>   label (line 986) actually solves the
>   problem. so the the code that works
>   for me look like this:
>
> ```
>     response = dialog.run()
>     # dialog.destroy() 
>
>     if response == gtk.RESPONSE_ACCEPT:
>         self.selected_tab.set_label(entry.get_text())
>
>     dialog.destroy()
> ```
>
> maybe there is some problem with gtk
>   and dialogs, but i haven't found any
>   code changes connected with gtk in the
>   version 0.4.1 diff.

**EDIT**: guake 0.4.2 can change the tab name correctly

Comment: this doesnt answer the question

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure this works for guake, it works for most terminal emulators.
You can include an echo on your scripts to change the terminal title:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;your_title_here\007"
```

Comment: that didnt work, when I typed it in the terminal.

Comment: That's because your shell's prompt will usually set it to the current working directory. Check the PS1 variable.

Comment: It doesn't work on my Ubuntu 15.10 either. I checked `echo $PS1` which shows something like `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$` what does this help me solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Bit of a hack, but this will rename the current terminal to whatever you ssh'ed for.

```
function ssh() {
    guake -r "$@";
    /usr/bin/ssh $@
}
```

Also if you update your PROMPT_COMMAND, you can have a function to update the terminal name each time. Although this will not work for your ssh problem as it only changes the name after the command has run.

e.g.

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND=renameTerminal

function renameTerminal() {
    guake -r "$SOMENAME";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I want to change the tab name in guake, I just right-click the tab name and left-click rename. A pop-up box opens to type the new name into.

Comment: sure, but how can you add this to a script?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply change the tabname with

```
guake -r newtabname
```

If you want to get the latest running command, use for example

```
echo "!!" | cut -f 1 -d " "
```

`!!` is expanded by bash when you type it. It's not expanded by alias substitution. So you have to use the `history` built-in to do the expansion to put it in an alias:

```
alias setguaketitle='guake -r $(echo "$(history -p !! )"| cut -f 1 -d " ")'
```

when your last command was

```
echo this is a test
```

then calling

```
setguaketitle
```

will set the title to "echo".

Answer (score 0):

If you change your shell to zsh, you can add this to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
preexec() {
    echo -n '\e]0;'
    echo -nE "$1"
    print -nP '  (%~)'
    echo -n '\a'
}
```

and it will show the current command and the current working directory.  This works for all terminal emulators, not just guake.

To install zsh:

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
```

to try it out just say

```
zsh
```

to make it your default for new terminals:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

Comment: zsh doesnt work at all with guake :(

Comment: Oh, right, I remember hitting that problem before.  But at least some of the bugs relating to it now seem to be fixed, eg <http://guake.org/ticket/49>.