# Annoying autorenaming in Guake

Tags: 12.10, guake

I love Guake drop-down terminal, but it has an annoying issue. When I use many tabs, I hate when the tab names rename each time I execute a command or navigate in one of them. I want to rename any tab and maintain the name in all sessions. For instance, when I use Midnight Commander and I enter in a long path folder, the tab expands and it's horrible. I see tab name `mc [user@machine_name]:/weird/long/infinite/path` when I navigate to `/weird/long/infinite/path` folder.

Can I have always the same name for each tab, even when renaming it manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found a way to disable the annoying renaming. I found in my guake Python script (in version 0.4.3-3) in lines 996 to 1002:

```
def on_terminal_title_changed(self, vte, box):
    use_them = self.client.get_bool(KEY("/general/use_vte_titles"))
    if not use_them:
        return
    page = self.notebook.page_num(box)
    self.tabs.get_children()[page].set_label(vte.get_window_title())
```

As the script shows, `/general/use_vte_titles` key prevents the autorenaming feature. It is Guake uses GConf to configure his options ([explanation](http://lists.guake.org/pipermail/guake/2011-June/000575.html)). I had to install [gconf-editor package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/gconf-editor) to edit Guake options executing `sudo apt-get install gconf-editor`. Then I executed `gconf-editor`, I browsed to `/apps/guake/general` and unmarked `use_vte_titles` key. Closed the editor. Next time I executed Guake the autorenaming feature was disabled.

Now, all the tabs are named `Terminal` and if I rename one, it still named all the session with the same name.
It would be helpful to add this key into the Guake preferences dialogue. But this solution worked anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with `gsettings` on the commandline?

Comment: @qed should work like that: `gconftool --set /apps/guake/general/use_vte_titles --type boolean true`

Answer (score 18):

just run

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/guake/general/use_vte_titles --type boolean false
```

and restart your terminal,

easy as pie(3.14)

Answer (score 4):

On the command line:

vim ~/.gconf/apps/guake/general/%gconf.xml

There should be an entry something like this:

```
<entry name="use_vte_titles" mtime="1404143215" type="bool" value="true"/>
```

Just change it to:

```
<entry name="use_vte_titles" mtime="1404143215" type="bool" value="false"/>
```

Save the file and restart guake.

Answer (score 2):

Consider simply shortening the terminal title. The algorithm is defined in `.bashrc`, the terminal title will be respected by Guake as you have noticed:

My `.bashrc` contains the following:

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1X=$(pwd | sed -r "s-^$HOME/--;s-^$HOME-~-;s-^(.[^/]*)/.*/-\1/.../-")'
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}"'$PS1X'"\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

The host name is not shown anymore, and only the first and the last path component is shown:

`$HOME` -> `~`

`$HOME/some/deep/sub/dir` -> `some/.../dir`

`/usr/local/deeply/inside/there` -> `/usr/.../there`

With this setting, the tab buttons are narrow enough but still contain useful information.

See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/3497885/946850

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26844/19205

Comment: It is a good option, but my question was 'Can I have always the same name for each tab, even when renaming it manually?'. It can be achieved with my approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I had this issue as well and I am so surprised that it still appears in recent Guake versions. In the latest version I think there is an option to name the terminals as `Terminal 1`, `Terminal 2` etc which doesn't help much either.

In the past few years I have employed a simple script in my `.zshrc` (I use Zsh terminal, but you can apply something similar in Bash).

```
function chpwd {
 if [ -e ".guakerc" ]; then
   setupguake
 else
    guake -r ${PWD##*/}
 fi
}

function setupguake() {
  . $(pwd)/.guakerc

  if ((${+name})); then
    guake -r ${name}
  fi
}
```

Essentially what this does, it monitors any directory change (through `chpwd`) and if a `.guakerc` file is found it runs it. Inside that file you can setup the guake title and many other things.

If no `.guakerc` file is found (the most usual case), it just sets the folder name as the terminal name. So if you are in a folder named `/home/username/Development/social-app` it will rename the terminal as `social-app`.

Hope it helps!