# How to backup guake's settings

Tags: backup, guake

I've worked a lot on configuring guake to my needs but I can't find a way to export these changes (doesn't seem to be related to gnome-terminal's profiles). Is there a way to backup my "guake profile" and then restore it in another pc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Luckily you don't need to be an expert on dconf anymore:

```
guake --restore-preferences ~/myguakeprefs 
guake --save-preferences ~/myguakeprefs
```

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE 2019

*OUTDATED* please check the new answer that includes `--restore-preferences` and `--save-preferences`

Backing up gconf `/apps/guake` and `/schemas/apps/guake` paths recursively.

#### Backup

```
gconftool-2 --dump /apps/guake > apps-guake.xml
gconftool-2 --dump /schemas/apps/guake > schemas-apps-guake.xml
```

#### Restore

```
gconftool-2 --load apps-guake.xml
gconftool-2 --load schemas-apps-guake.xml
```

Plus backing up directory `~/.gconf/apps/guake` should do it.

More info [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/490041/134645) or [issue 292](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/292) and [issue 323](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/323)