# How to change the name of Guake terminal?

Tags: command-line, guake

My tab name of guake terminal is always "Terminal", whether I open a file or not. I hope that it can display "[num] filename".

Answer (score 0):

this is discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18975/can-i-change-the-name-of-the-guake-tab-to-show-the-current-command). But I can recommend you to use [Tilda](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda) terminal. I switched from Guake to that, for more customization options.

Comment: Thanks. But in Tilda the tab name is always "Tilda".

Comment: I have Tilda 1.3.1 and I have the Folder path in tabs